# TwitCurl and full timeline tweet retrieval

Tags: c++, twitter

Fairly inexperienced programmer attempting to complete a little project. I'm trying to write a little bit of C++ code using the TwitCurl library to retrieve a list of all the tweets a user has made. I've run into a bit of a problem though. Using

twitterObj.timelineUserGet(); 
twitterObj.getLastWebResponse( replyMsg );

replyMsg only seems to contain around twenty or so of a user's most recent tweets. I'm not sure how to reach "further back" to get the full list of tweets. The only work around I've been able to come up with so far is grabbing the available timeline, saving it locally, tokenizing the tweet ID's contained in the timeline, then deleting those tweets from Twitter, and then grabbing the next set of tweets, adding the next set to the local copy. This process creates a local copy of all tweets, but destroys a user's timeline. Obviously this is not really a "solution".

I've done a little research and it also seems that even if I find a specific solution that will return more than 20 tweets, I am still eventually going to hit a hard limit of not being able to get data that's more than three weeks old. (I am ok with this)

Can anyone suggest a way to return a user's full timeline?